# What is the different between Parse-server and Parse-server-example on ParsePlatform on GitHub?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I am doing migration from my Parse hosted applications to ParseServer running on AWS or Heroku slowly.

The Heroku "guide to deploy to Heroku and MongoLab" uses "Parse-server-example" on GitHub while the ParseServer wiki mentions cloning "Parse-server" instead. In particular, "Parse-server" repository does not contain the "cloud\main.js" file which is the cloud function file.

If I want to run ParseServer locally or on AWS, which one of those two should I use? What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 4):

You should clone the "parse-server-example" since it sounds like you need a starter project to run locally. Then you can start adding your existing Parse code to this new project.

The "parse-server" repository contains the source code for the Parse Server npm package, which is used by the "parse-server-example" to run a server.

Comment: When moving to production, will I only need to deploy my cloned/amended Parse-server-example app to Heroku or AWS? I will only need to modify the Cloud code "main.js" file.

Comment: Yeah, basically. If you want to keep things simple, use the Parse Server Heroku Button. It's a simple one-click way to deploy a parse server that is based on the parse-server-example code and sets up a database for you at MongoLab. Then all you have to do is write your cloud functions in the main.js file. This will let you work locally and your production server will be ready. Here's the link: https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example