# Getting error 'Cannot find module 'parse-server'

Tags: npm, parse-server

I am trying to run Parse server which is available on link:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

I have done some pre-requisites related to MongoDB and some other concepts. When I try to run parse server using command:

```
node parseServer.js
```

But this command gives me an error as:

```
'Cannot find module 'parse-server'
```

Again, I installed parse-server module using command:

```
sudo npm install -g parse-server
```

After installing this module, I tried again to run parse server, but still I am getting same error.

Some help would be really appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Parse Server example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example), Parse server  is used as a like node js module.

[What is the different between Parse-server and Parse-server-example on ParsePlatform on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470157/what-is-the-different-between-parse-server-and-parse-server-example-on-parseplat)